# circuitikz as a float

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, circuitikz

I used `wrapfigure` with its package to try to make a `circuitikz` as a float to put text beside, but I got a warning like

> "wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment"

and then it drops my circuit on the next page... So how do we do to make a `circuitikz` as a float?

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[h]{r}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to [short, o-] node[anchor=east]{$V_{cc}$}(0,0)
to [R=$R_{4}$] (2,0)
to [R=$R_7$] (4,0)
to [D*, l_=$D_1$] (4,-2)
(4, -4) to [pC=$C_1$]  (4, -2)
(4,-4) to[short]node[ground]{} (4, -4);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{\textbf{Circuit équivalent de \textit{attack}}}
\label{fig:attack}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Just a minor remark: if you want to change the general style of the captions, use the caption package instead of using commands in every caption.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `newfloat` package to make your circuit a float and as @MaxNoe said in his comment use`caption`package to format your style of the captions, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{circuit}
\renewcommand{\circuitname}{Circuit}

\usepackage[
format={hang},
textfont={bf},
]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuit}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to [short, o-] node[anchor=east]{$V_{cc}$}(0,0)
to [R=$R_{4}$] (2,0)
to [R=$R_7$] (4,0)
to [D*, l_=$D_1$] (4,-2)
(4, -4) to [pC=$C_1$]  (4, -2)
(4,-4) to[short]node[ground]{} (4, -4);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuit \'equivalent de \textit{attack}}
\label{fig:attack}
\end{circuit}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice thanks for the `float` package, but i don't understand how to put my text beside. With wrapfig, it's just adding `\begin{wrapfigure}[h]**{r}{width}**` . What is it with `float` package?

Comment: Read the wrap fig manual,  it says how you can get a floating wrapfig. Hint: There are lower and uppercase options for the placement.